# WordPress On Subdomain Blank

Tags: php, wordpress, subdomain, cpanel

I have a domain that works like a charm www.mydomain.com. Recently I wanted to add a subdomain like myotherweb.mydomain.com, so i add my subdomain from my cPanel and upload my Wordpress (works on XAMPP) to subdomain directory.

After that I try to open myotherweb.mydomain.com; the result is a blank page.

So I try to open myotherweb.mydomain.com/wp-admin and the Wordpress login page shows up, and I can log in to my wp-admin dashboard page. But when I try to edit a page, the edit page is blank.

What is happening in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this case happens if transfer of wordpress is not proper or `.htaccess` is not proper set.

> 1. `.htaccess` settings for subdomain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

For more reference you can check on [Wordpres Codex htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

> 2. Transfer wordpress from one domain to another
>      This is most common problem happens to many when transfer from one domain to another.

1. Update Your **wp-config.php** File

   `define('WP_HOME','http://myotherweb.mydomain.com');`
   `define('WP_SITEURL','http://myotherweb.mydomain.com');`
2. Update urls in sql

For this open your exported database in text-editor like notepad+, sublime or netbeans, and do find and replace urls `mydomain.com` to `myotherweb.mydomain.com` and try import on live again,

or if you are not familiar with this or this is boring task for you then you don't need to panic, there is one plugin available to do this task for you very easily.

Install [Wordpress duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) in your xampp and use as instruction given on [plugin site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) or [this reference site](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-move-wordpress-to-a-new-domain-without-losing-seo/), after that upload new wordpress site generated by plugin on your subdomain.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try to update my htaccess and my wp-config and sql. I think there's no need another setting. brb.

Comment: Okay try it. If one not work there are other options of  `htaccess` available on wordpress site. For that url is already given. you can try that.

Comment: Hi, i have copied your example htaccess to my Wordpress root htaccess, and add define home and siteurl on my wp-config, also update my database home and url location to my subdomain url, but it's still blank, what i miss?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by install wordpress from my cPanel, and copy this setting from new Wordpress installation wp-config :

```
AUTH_KEY
SECURE_AUTH_KEY
LOGGED_IN_KEY
NONCE_KEY
AUTH_SALT
SECURE_AUTH_SALT
LOGGED_IN_SALT
NONCE_SALT
```

then replace my Wordpress project wp-config, and it's magic.
I don't know why it's necessary.